# Spring boot web app returns different error codes in different servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

I have a spring app deployed on two servers (dev and prod). Because of a bug in one of the service classes, a NPE is thrown. The dev instance displays a 500 error when hitting the respective controller, but the PROD instance shows a 404 error instead, for the same controller.

What would be a good way to find the cause for such discrepancy? I would expect both servers to show a 500 error.

Comment: So the same request is sent to both servers by the client to the same application on different servers and you are getting two different error codes, instead of  an expected single error code?

Comment: @electricchef right, a request sent to dev will return 500 and the same request, but sent to prod, will return 404 instead

Comment: This could be because of both servers are having different Database and different data. In case of PROD data is not available in some validation before the code which throws the 500 throws the 404. While n DEV data is available, so after availability check some code after that throwing 500 error.

Comment: @GauravJeswani is there a way to test that?  Would you find a piece of data known in one, not the other, see what comes back, and then run another combination, not known in both, etc. ?

Comment: @electricchef I think here you want to tag the author of question. Or it is for me?

Comment: Both, but it seems posters are tagged/notified by default.

Comment: It's a get request. DEV and PROD both point to the same DB. Example GET /send-notif-for-id/12345   a NPE is thrown because of a list that should be traversed but the list is null, and we get 500/404 depending on the server